# Erro na Impressão de Matriz C

Tags: c, matriz

Estou tentando preencher uma matriz de maneira recursiva para obter quantos valores do vetor são iguais, porém não está dando certo e não sei onde está o problema.

- A matriz é gerada a partir de comparação de 2 strings
- Se os valores entre o vetor1[x] e o vetor2[y] forem iguais a posição matriz[x][y] recebe um valor
- Se não forem, um dos valores da matriz é repetido

Segue o código que possuo:

```
int rec(char vet1[], char vet2[], int mat[][tam], int x, int y)
{

  if(mat[x][y] != NULL ) \\  a matriz completa é preenchida com NULL inicialmente, seguida por primeira linha e coluna com 0. Desta forma a recursão pode parar.
  {
     return mat[x][y];
  }
  else
  {
      if(vet1[x] == vet2[y]) \\ compara 2 valores de um vetor de char, se forem iguais, preenche a posição da matriz com a posição anterior + 1
      {
         mat[x][y] = rec(vet1, vet2, mat, x-1, y-1) + 1;
      }
      else // mas se não forem iguais, repete o maior valor achado anteriormente na matriz
      {
         mat[x-1][y] = rec(vet1, vet2, mat, x-1, y);
         mat[x][y-1] = rec(vet1, vet2, mat, x, y-1);
         if(mat[x-1][y] < mat[x][y-1])
         {
            mat[x][y] = mat[x][y-1];
         }
         else
         {
            mat[x][y] = mat[x-1][y];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Poste o código que está sendo executado.

Comment: Falta declaração de variáveis, inicialização, ... `mat[x][y] != NULL`, por exemplo, não pode estar correcto!!!

Comment: Esta parte do código estava gerando problema realmente, pois a matriz compreendia que 0 também era nulo e eu não estava inicializando de forma correta. Desta forma não fazia o cálculo exato.